# Liberty Profile: Can't get standard openid connect claims in ID token with LDAP/AD registry

Tags: websphere-liberty, openid-connect

We have configured an instance of WebSphere Liberty Profile v18.0.0.1 as an openid connect provider
The authentication flows work well.
The problem is that we don't get the "standard" OIDC claims in the `ID Token`: `name`, `family_name`, `given_name`, `middle_name`, `birthdate`...
The authentication request asks for the  `"openid email profile phone"` scopes
The claims we receive bundled in the `ID Token` are: `sub`, `at_hash`, `realmName`, `uniqueSecurityName`, `groupsIds`, `iss`, `aud`, `exp`, `iat`, `nonce`

Q:

- how to get the other claims in the ID Token? shouldn't them be automatically mapped by WLP?
- I presume this is quite standard to map AD attributes to use AD as a registry for the openid connect server in liberty. do we have to use stanzas like `"scopeToClaimMap"`or `"attributeConfiguration"`as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_scopes_claims_userinfo.html) ? if so is there an example that map all the `ID Token` standard attributes to the AD attribute?
- Is there something missing or wrong in our `server.xml`config?
  Thanks

extracts from `server.xml`:

```
<featureManager>
   ...
   <feature>openidConnectServer-1.0</feature>
 </featureManager>

 <openidConnectProvider id="OP" 
                       oauthProviderRef="Oauth" signatureAlgorithm="RS256" 
                       keyStoreRef="..." keyAliasName="..."  issuerIdentifier="..." 
                       idTokenLifetime="1m">
</openidConnectProvider>

<oauthProvider id="Oauth" 
               jwtAccessToken="true" 
               logoutRedirectURL="..." 
               accessTokenLifetime="60">
   <localStore>
     <client name="..." secret="..." displayname="..." redirect="..." 
             scope="openid email profile phone"
             preAuthorizedScope="openid email profile phone" 
             enabled="true">
     </client>
   </localStore>
</oauthProvider>

<ldapRegistry id="..." host="..." port="..." baseDN="..."
              ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" 
              recursiveSearch="true" sslEnabled="true" 
              bindDN="..." bindPassword="...">
</ldapRegistry>

<oauth-roles>
   <authenticated>
      <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
   </authenticated>
</oauth-roles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to get the standard claims from an LDAP/AD registry, is to add this to`server.xml` (`"customClaims"`is a tag inside `"openidConnectProvider"` and not an attribute as state in the other answer, and the claim names are separated by spaces, not commas)

```
<openidConnectProvider id="OP" oauthProviderRef="Oauth" ...
   <customClaims>family_name given_name ...</customClaims>
</openidConnectProvider>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The requested scopes impact the contents returned when calling userinfo API.
2. Liberty OIDC id_token only emit required claims by default, but can be configured to explicitly fetch additional LDAP attributes as id_token's claims. For example, if you want to include `family_name`, and `given_name` in id_token, your `openidConnectProvider` configuration looks like:

   ```
   <openidConnectProvider id="OP" oauthProviderRef="Oauth" ...
      customClaims="family_name, given_name">

   </openidConnectProvider>
   ```
3. The claim to registry mapping, and the use of custom attribute in LDAP are similar to userinfo, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_config_scopes_claims_userinfo.html

   Here are some tips:
   The custom claim name can be different from LDAP attribute name, and you can define mapping rule.
   For example, if the LDAP attribute for `family_name` is `familyName`, your configuration will look like this:

   ```
   <openidConnectProvider id="OP" oauthProviderRef="Oauth"
   ```

   customClaimsEnabled="true" 
   customClaims="family_name, given_name">

   < claimToUserRegistryMap family_name="familyName"/>

   < claimToUserRegistryMap given_name="givenName"/>

   < /openidConnectProvider>

   Finally, Liberty LDAP user registry can only search a list of pre-defined attributes. You can skip this extra steps if all required attributes are in the predefined list. If you want to use LDAP attribute that is not defined as Liberty federated registry property, you will need do additional LDAP setup.
   For example, say you want to use LDAP attribute `loginCount` in OIDC, but `loginCount` is not a property defined by Liberty LDAP registry,  you will need configure `"attributeConfiguration"`, like this

   ```
   <ldapRegistry ......
      <attributeConfiguration>
         <attribute name="loginCount" propertyName="seeAlso" entityType="PersonAccount"/> 
      </attributeConfiguration>
      ...
   </ldapRegistry>
   ```

   For a person object, here is the list of predefined federated repository properties --

   ```
   "uid", 
   "cn", 
   "sn", 
   "preferredLanguage", 
   "displayName", 
   "initials", 
   "mail", 
   "ibmPrimaryEmail", 
   "jpegPhoto", 
   "labeledURI", 
   "carLicense", 
   "telephoneNumber", 
   "facsimileTelephoneNumber", 
   "pager", 
   "mobile", 
   "homePostalAddress", 
   "postalAddress", 
   "roomNumber", 
   "l", 
   "localityName", 
   "st", 
   "stateOrProvinceName", 
   "street", 
   "postalCode", 
   "city", 
   "employeeType", 
   "employeeNumber", 
   "manager", 
   "secretary", 
   "departmentNumber", 
   "title", 
   "ibmJobTitle", 
   "c", 
   "countryName", 
   "givenName", 
   "homeAddress", 
   "businessAddress", 
   "description", 
   "businessCategory", 
   "seeAlso", 
   "kerberosId", 
   "photoURL", 
   "photoURLThumbnail" .
   ```

   For more detail, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/wimdomain.xsdfile.html

   If you use those attributes, you can skip additional LDAP setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This should be part of the official documentation as the official doc is quite confusing on those. I can't even find a trace of the `wimdomain.xsd` file in the latest WLP doc (v18.0.0.1) ...

Comment: you changed back the code corrections I made a few hours ago... In WLP v18.0.0.1, There is no `customClaimsEnabled="true"`attribute and the `customClaims` is not an attribute but a tag by itself inside the `openidConnectProvider `. Your config does not work as is at least in v18.0.0.1... And also you messed up with the code formatting I corrected before...So I retract my vote as the code is not correct, at leat in v18.0.0.1

Comment: I did not realize you have correct the code format.  The customClaimsEnabled is an internal attribute to disable this function in my testing, I should not put it here. Feel free to update the sample code